# How to configure Helidon MP security

Tags: java, security, helidon

I've been learning *Helidon MP* features from [github](https://github.com/oracle/helidon/tree/master/examples) as it is one of the most reliable sources due to the weak community of framework. However, the configurations and instructions represented for **security** is a bit difficult to get. The examples work fine for demo applications where usernames, passwords, roles and realms are hardcoded into *application.yaml* file but as the users are always stored in database, sometimes even roles are read from database wrapped in a Role object. I'm sure that there exists a more dynamic configuration to Helidon security; for instance, I read about implementing **AuthenticationProvider** and **AuthorizationProvider** and adding providers to **Security** object but how is that object registered in the application? Any links or code samples would be very useful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Helidon MP comes with a full set of [documentation related to security providers](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/security/02_providers), including [a section on how to extend security](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/se/security/05_extensibility).